# Not able to connect Linux Azure VM from Windows Azure VM

Tags: mysql, ssis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-linux

I have 2 azure VMs 1st is Linux machine(ubuntu 18.04) and 2nd is windows azure vm. I have MySql database in Linux machine. I want to move the data from Linux MySql database to SQL Server Database which is hosted on windows Azure machine. I am creating a SSIS package to perform this operation but I am not able to connect to the Linux machine, I have open all the required ports (22,3306,1433) ports in all inbound and outbound rules in both vm but still I am not able to create successful connection.
Both the servers are in same vnet and load balancer is not applicable.

Comment: do you have nsg or udr in the vnet\subnet?

Comment: Yes we have nsg in vnet

Comment: Is there any firewall inside both VMs? If so, Have you opened these ports in NSG and VM firewall?

Comment: We have open the ports in both firewall and nsg. Also we try after closing the firewall for both the systems but still no luck.

Comment: Could you connect to the Linux VM from another Azure VM or local VM? Or test`telnet linuxprivateVMip 22` on the windows VM?

Comment: I am able to connect Linux VM from putty from both host/local machine and from inside the Azure windows VM. I have tried psping to ping the Linux VM but it didn't work out , let me check for telnet

Comment: By default, the Azure VMs in the same subnet could access, any port is opened in NSG. How do you connect to the Linux VM from Windows VM. It should be using its private IP address.

Comment: Any update on your side?  Is this issue fixed?

Comment: Yeah, this fixed. For me the main criteria was to connect with mysql (Linux machine) from ssis (windows machine). The issue is with the user we were using, we create a user and provided all the rights to that new user, from this new user we are able to connect. Thanks for the support and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster.

For me the main criteria was to connect with mysql (Linux machine) from ssis (windows machine). The issue is with the user we were using, we created a user and provided all the rights to that new user, from this new user we are able to connect.